# ".... and then Judah decides to eliminate his mistress." Is it correct to use "eliminate" for "kill"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In a review for the 1989 film "Crimes and Misdemeanors" a critic says: "...and after his mistress has been eliminated, Judah decides..." meaning "has been killed".  I always thought of "eliminate" as a verb meaning to remove or defeat.

> Eliminate - to remove (something that is not wanted or needed), to defeat and remove (a team, player, etc.) from a competition http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eliminate

Can we use it instead of "kill" as in "Bloody dictators won't hesitate to eliminate their opposers."

Comment: Yes. Eliminate is a euphemism for kill

Comment: @mplungjan Not even a euphemism, but a direct meaning.

Comment: I think this is General Reference, but OP needs to bear in mind that such use of *eliminate* is effectively ***figurative***. A dictator could equally well eliminate any opposition by *banishing* his opponents - they'd still be alive, but no longer able to compete with the incumbent ruler. By the same token, he could figuratively *kill* the opposition by banishing them, or locking them up.

Comment: Another very common slang today for "kill", particularly in action movies, (it always sounds rather silly to me) is "take out".  We have to take out! the orange robot! sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Yes***, the use of ***eliminate*** for ***kill***, or more typically, ***murder***, is well-established.

Several dictionaries record this usage (sometimes, but not always, labelling it as *slang*):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eliminate):

> ***eliminate***: *<sup>slang</sup> to murder in a cold-blooded manner.*

[MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/eliminate):

> ***eliminate***: *to murder someone who is considered to be a problem.*

[Cambridge Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/eliminate):

> ***eliminate***: *<sup>slang</sup> to murder someone.*

[Infoplease](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/eliminate):

> ***eliminate***: *to eradicate or kill: to eliminate the enemy.*

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eliminate?rdfrom=Eliminate):

> ***eliminate***: *<sup>slang</sup> To kill (a person or animal).*

Furthemore, several thesauruses list *eliminate* as a synonym in the *kill*-constellation of words.  For one example, [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/assassinate) even has *eliminate* as a synonym for ***assassinate***.

Comment: One good reference makes the Q a GR.

Comment: I have no problem with closing it as a GR, though now that I've submitted an answer, I'll abstain from voting.

Comment: With so many references in your answer I have to agree: it is GR. I tried to delete it but it is not possible after someone has answered.  Interestingly, I had looked up the word in three dictionaries before posting the question and they didn't mention "kill".